# python library that is the inverse of urllib?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

urllib fetches data from urls right? is there a python library that can do the reverse of that and send data to urls instead (for example, to a site you are managing)? and if so, is that library compatible with apache?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does sending data to a URL mean? The usual way to do that is just via an HTTP POST, and `urllib` (and `urllib2`) handle that just fine.

Comment: forgive me i am new to the world of web design. what little i know of urllib tells me that you can get data from forms etc. so what i meant by "sending data to a URL" is the capability to then supply data to forms. url can handle this too, i guess?

Comment: urllib and urllib2 can post form data but it can get a bit tedious. If you're trying to fill out web forms and/or emulate a human user, I'd recommend taking a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Comment: @Marc Correct me if I'm wrong, but when a page submits a form, it's usually over a simple get/post request, right? Why would this be difficult to do with `urllib`/`urllib2`?

Answer (score 2):

urllib can send data associated with a request by using GET or POST.

`urllib2.urlopen(url, data)` where data is a dict of key-values representing the data you're sending. See [this link on usage](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Network/SubmitPOSTData.htm). 
Then process that data on the server-side.

If you want to send data any other way, you should use some other protocol such as FTP (see [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)).